# Customizing image styles in Reactstrap Uncontrolled Carousel Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, carousel, reactstrap

I'm running into some issues with utilizing the Uncontrolled Carousel Component in Reactstrap.  I've been able to use the code from their documentation to get everthing working except for styling the images on each slide.  I'd like to use an overlay to make the image darker to allow the text to stand out.  However, I'm not familiar with how to do this with their component.  In Bootstrap, it was very easy to apply a custom class to the  tag.  Because the Reactstrap Carousel only accesses the image from the original array, I can't apply the same custom class.  Is there another way to solve this issue?

```
const TESTIMONIES = [
{
    src: './img/mcphersons.jpg',
    header: ' ',
    caption: "Caption 1",
    key: '1'
},
{
    src: './img/hootons.jpeg',
    header: ' ',
    caption: "Caption 2",
    key: '2'
},
{
    src: './img/berlangas.JPG',
    header: ' ',
    caption: "Caption 3",
    key: '3'
}
];

const Carousel = () => (
<Row className='mt-5 mb-5'>
    <Col md={8} className="mx-auto">
        <UncontrolledCarousel items={TESTIMONIES} />
    </Col>
</Row>
);


export default Carousel;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add a class <Row className='mt-5 mb-5 yourClass'> here?

Comment: @nanquim it looks like that applied it, but it goes across the whole row and not just the picture.  Turns out you can apply it to the <UncontrolledCarousel /> component directly and it fits within the size of the carousel.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`.carousel-item > img{ max-height: 260px !important; }`

carousel-item is one of the classes used by the uncontrolled component of reactstarp inside which resides the image component.Thus this is how I did it basically i have overwritten the actual class